# How to check if 2 vectors are the same in which NA is treated as a normal value?

Tags: r, indexing, na

I would to check if 2 vectors are element-wise identical, even with NA. For example

```
A <- c("A", NA, "C", "D", NA)
C <- c("A", "C", "C", "D", NA)
A == C
```

returns `TRUE   NA TRUE TRUE NA`, whereas I expect `TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE TRUE`. Could you please elaborate on how to do do?

Comment: Use the `compareNA` function from the duplicate. You could also do `mapply(identical, A,C)`